# Proof for sphere eversion

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, geometric-topology

Do you know where I can find (preferably online) a proof for the possibility of a sphere eversion?

Comment: Maybe [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.10466.pdf), or some of the references cited in its introduction

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Yes, that was what I wanted. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a question of proof acceptance:
Let you impress by the famous [video 'Outside In'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wO61D9x6lNY) by Bill Thurston and collaborators ...

Or you may wish to invest more time and look into [Scott Carter's book](https://www.southalabama.edu/mathstat/personal_pages/carter/evert_book-2.pdf).

*Added in edit:*
A less informal & more technical reference is [Bednorz & Bednorz](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.10466.pdf), as proposed in Akiva Weinberger's comment to the OP.

Comment: I watched that video today, it's why I made the post :) I actually wanted a more formal proof, if possible. The book is pretty big, but it also seems to be on the more intuitive side, no? I just looked at a couple of pages of the eversion, though

Comment: @J.Dionisio The original proof used what is called the $h$-principle, and was a particular form of what became called "Smale-Hirsch theory". It was extremely inexplicit, and proceeded by studying the space of all immersions of $S^2$ into $\Bbb R^3$, and found that there is only one path-component in this space. Therefore there must exist a path between any of your favorite two immersions! The existence of explicit formulas giving this eversion is a newer development.

Comment: I think, though, that the general concept of the $h$-principle came quite a bit later than Smale's original 1957 proof of sphere eversion. Smale's proof, however inexplicit, is pretty elegant and not too hard to digest.